# Spring Mongo Repository - Best way to implement soft delete on mongo Repository?

Tags: spring, mongodb, jhipster, soft-delete

I need to implement a soft delete on all my Entities , I'm using jHipster, using Spring framework with MongoRepository. 
By adding a Boolean field or DateTime field, and check whether is true or has DateTime (in case of DateTime field).

So I thought about adding an event listener on delete events and Listing events.

- the problem that I can't find anywhere how to stop events from happening.
  For example stopping the delete event and make a save statement with the new value for soft delete field

So the question is Is there a way to stop the event and make soft delete happen ??

If no how to make soft delete the cleanest way ??

PS : please I know I can make update every time my self but I can't because I have so much code to change.

Comment: do you delete and query for entitities only with declared repositories interfaces which extends  MongoRepository<?,?> ? do you want override default behavior of  MongoRepository ?

Comment: @VladMamaev yes i use declared interfaces, yes i if it's a good way to override why not ?? what i mean with good way is i don't need to change anything in the future if the base repository is updated.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.customize-base-repository

Comment: thank you @VladMamaev for your suggestion , it's seems like a good lead however i think it will take some time and work, is there another way like using events , for example alter the query before execution in event driven way ??